# The propagated error in the measurement

Tags: calculus

The volume of the cube is claimed to be $27$ inches, correct to within $0.027$ $in^3$. Use differentials to estimate the propagated error in the measurement of the side of the cube.

I got

$$V=27$$

$v=x^3$, which $x=3$ inches

$$dV=3x^2\,dx$$

$$0.027=27dx$$

$dx=+2$ and $-2$

But I am not sure what the answer of this question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that
$$dV=3x^2\,dx$$

For the interpretation, $dV$ is the error in volume, $x$ is the side of the cube, and $dx$ is the error in the side of the cube. Substituting, we get

$$0.027=3 \cdot (3)^2 \cdot dx$$
$$dx=\frac{0.027}{3 \cdot 9}$$
$$=0.001$$

Comment: Shall I write the error in the volume is 0.001?

Comment: @Rich: No: write the error in the measurement of the side of the cube is $0.001$.